# Prove that $\sqrt{(1+x)}<1+\frac{1}{2}x$ $\forall x>0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I was just practicing some real analysis for an upcoming quiz and I just wanted some feedback on if my proof was written sufficiently. The question's above, my answer's below. Thanks!

Pf: Let $x>0,$ $ x \in (0,x)$, and let $f(x) = \sqrt{(1+x)}-(1+\frac{1}{2}x)$. Observe that $f(0) = \sqrt{1+0} - (1 + \frac{1}{2}0) = 1 - 1 = 0.$ Also observe that $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x}} - \frac{1}{2}.$ We know that $\forall x>0$, $\sqrt{1+x}>1$ implies that $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x}} - \frac{1}{2} < 0.$ Thus $f(x)$ is decreasing by the Decreasing Criterion and $f(x) < 0 \Rightarrow$ $\sqrt{(1+x)}-(1+\frac{1}{2}x) < 0 \Rightarrow$  $\sqrt{(1+x)}<1+\frac{1}{2}x$ $\forall x>0.$

Comment: There are some minor mistakes in it, as shown by the answers below but I want to laud you for your creativity in defining a new function as the difference of the LHS and RHS, finding its derivative and proving its decreasing, and linking it back to the original question. I was thinking of approaching it with induction and then realised its not applicable to real numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing I noticed: you say to let $x \in (0,x)$,
but that is impossible, since every element of the interval $(0,x)$
is less than $x$.

Second thing: I think you have made this harder than it needs to be.
Look at what you get if you take the square of each side.

Comment: That would have been much easier! Thank you for your input. Would it have been fine to say let x be in the interval (0, y) where y is a positive real number?

Comment: If you really need $x$ to be _inside_ an open interval, yes, I suppose you can just take the upper end of the interval to be any larger number, even $x+1$ (as long as the facts you need to be true on the interval are true). I think $x\in(0,+\infty)$ also works for many purposes (including yours). But for some theorems I think you don't _need_ to show anything on an open interval containing $x$; you might only need to show function $g$ is continuous on $[0,x]$ and differentiable on $(0,x)$. A theorem is like a contract; sometimes it pays to read the "fine print".

Answer (score 1):

Let $x>0$, then $\frac{1}{4}x^2>0$

By adding $1+x$ to both sides, we obtain:
$$1+x+\frac{1}{4}x^2>1+x$$It follows that:$$(1+\dfrac{1}{2}x)^2>1+x$$
Since both sides are positive for all $x>0$, then $$\sqrt{(1+x)}<1+\dfrac{1}{2}x$$